# Pass Javascript variable to laravel include?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

How can i pass `js` `e` var to laravel `@include`. I tried the following code on `Ajax` callback but `e` is undefined ...

```
data['items'].forEach(function (e) {
    $('.filter_data').html(@include('frontend.products.product_layout',['product'=>e]));
});
```

How I can handle this?

Comment: did you put the js code inside the `body` tag or in `head` tag?

Comment: @Saengdaet body

Comment: have you tried to print the value of `e` before inserting it into the page? is it still undefined?

Comment: @Saengdaet Yes it is ok . but problem is using that into `@include`

Comment: I have one trick maybe u can try...
you can loop the items and return the array of html view from php instead of returning the  json object data.. So, when you got the response from ajax call, just loop the result and pass them

Comment: @Saengdaet ohom, good idea , but how can i use `laravel @include` in php ?

Comment: I have just answered, you can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how did your service process the data, but I will show you the example of returning the response with html view

Lets say if you have already had the data

```
$views = array();
foreach($arrData as $data) {
    $view = view("frontend.products.product_layout", ['product'=>e])->render();
    array_push($views, $view);
}
return response()->json(["data" => $views]);
```